# Is there a way in TeamCity to get projects status in an XML file?

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way to see an XML-represented snapshot of all the projects on our TeamCity build server?  Otherwise, is there another way to get this data suitable for consumption by a .NET app?  I see JetBrains has a Java API, but not a .NET one from what I could find.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RSS feeds for that purpose. The format can be customized, but it is not very well [documented](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Notifier+Templates+Configuration#NotifierTemplatesConfiguration-SyndicationFeedTemplate) how to do that.